# Why does html5shiv break jQuery-UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, html5shiv

I'm using the jQuery-UI Datepicker. It works fine, until I add this:

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript">
```

...then it no longer works (Datepicker no longer displays).

The Datepicker is the only jQuery-UI widget I'm using on this page, so I don't know if it breaks all jQuery-UI widgets, or just he Datepicker, but at any rate I'm wondering if html5shiv is or should be considered harmful.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: What order is the javascript loaded? Does jQueryUI javascript get loaded before or after html5shiv?

Comment: To start you diagnosis, try loading a-b, then b-a. If the symptoms change, then one script almost undoubtedly overwrites (at least in part) the other. If the symptoms are identical, then there's some sort of logical conflict.

Comment: The html5shiv comes after jQuery-UI; the only thing in the console is:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autoNumeric' 

...and appears to be unrelated...I'll now reverse the order of the two .js files...

Comment: It works now; I noticed I had forgot to add "</script>" to the end of the html5shiv bit (as seen above in my question). Odd that it worked at all, or, working at all, that it had that effect... Sorry, html5shivers - my bad!